# Noether's second theorem: its extension

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, gauge-theory, noethers-theorem

From what I 'understand', [Noether's second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_second_theorem) applies to infinite-dimensional symmetry groups. A classic, even historical, example is the invariance group of Riemannian spacetimes, i.e. the set of spacetime diffeomorphisms of GR.
Does Noether's second theorem also apply to quantum field theory (= the 'gauge groups')? Or is it confined to general relativity?